# How to calculate Tasseled Cap Transformation for Sentinel-2 images (from GEE) with different resolution of bands in R?

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, sentinel2

I downloaded Sentinel-2 stack from the Google Earth Engine. For the export I used resolution (`scale: 10`), while some bands there should have resolution 20 m (SWIR) or 60 m(e.g. Cirrus):

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: exportImgSentinel, 
  description: 'Sentinel', 
  folder: 'Sentinel', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'Sentinel', 
  region: region, 
  scale: 10, 
  crs: 'EPSG:4326'
});
```

Opening it as a RasterStack in R, I checked resolution of the stack:

```
res(Sentinel_weird_1)
[1] 8.983153e-05 8.983153e-05
```

**And the same for each separated band within**. OK, I tried to make some Tasseled Cap bands, typing formula using respective bands. I have got raster with only 2 different values, that is apparently wrong.
What to do in such cases? Should I:

- download separate bands from GEE with different resolution, and then `disaggregate` in R bands with 20 or 60 m resolution to the 10 m?
- or it will not work, since some data accuracy from 20-60 m resolution will be lost, and I should `aggregate` bands to the worst (60 m) resolution? That is, I can only make TCT maps with such bad resolution from Sentinel-2 images?

For Landsat data everything is clear. `res` function shows 30 m scale resolution. But I wanna have better map with 10 m resolution. Can I?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. The TC is developed for Landsat Thematic Mapper products. You have to adjust the coefficients used for the band transformation. There is [a paper from Shi & Xu (2019)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8836649) where they adjusted the coefficients to the S2 MSI at sensor reflectance.

There is also a [database for indices](https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/is.php?sensor_id=96), but there they simply use the Landsat coefficients for the S2 MSI data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the 20m resolution Sentinel. The 10m does not have the bands necessary for tasseled cap transformation. Coefficients apply to each of the 7 non-thermal bands.